# Context Free Grammar (CFG) Parser in Go

Tags: parsing, nlp, go

I am looking for a Go library providing CFG parsing (preferably not in Chomsky Normal Form). Has anybody heard of anything, or should I write it ? :)

Comment: Is it parsing for a CFG you specify, or for the Go language itself, or something else (parsing of arbitrary grammars to be specified at runtime) that you want?

Comment: @hardmath For a CFG I specify (NLP application)

Answer (score 4):

Do you know about [goyacc](http://golang.org/cmd/yacc/)?. Although it's not a library, but a code generator. Anyway it supports CFGs and it's IMO a pretty standard way to handle such tasks. (?)

Answer (score 2):

I cannot help you specifically with CFGs, but the [Go Dashboard](http://godashboard.appspot.com/) is a good central list of Go libraries.

Looking over it for parsers, two look helpful at first glace:

- [go-parse](https://github.com/vito/go-parse), modeled after Haskell's Parsec, and
- [peg](https://github.com/badgerodon/peg) for Parsing Expression Grammars.