# I have a number of regexes. How can I turn these into a lexer?

Tags: regex, go, pcre, lex

I wrote regexes for all the tokens in my programming language. How can I scan a piece of text for all of them? For instance, with these regexes:

```
int     = `[0-9]+`
float   = `[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?`
string  = `"[^"]+"`
char    = `'[^']'`
comment = `--(.+)?`
```

And this text:

```
12.3 12 "hey" 'y' -- Comment!
```

The output should be `{float at 1 - 5, int at 6 - 8, string at 9 - 14, char at 15 - 18, comment at 19 - 30}`. Is there a standard library function or a third-party library that can help me achieve this?

Comment: Is it intentional that every char is a string at the same time? To change that you might want to use '[^"]{2,}' instead of your version.

Comment: No, it's not... I tested this out with [regexr](http://www.regexr.com/) (all the tokens work on there, and I assumed go's regex syntax was the same as javascript's). I thought `'[^']'` meant that it matches a single quote, a single character that is not a single quote and another single quote?

Comment: Oh yeah, didn't see that you use single quote for chars and doubles for strings. In that case it's fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Context Free Grammar (CFG) Parser in Go](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12097565/context-free-grammar-cfg-parser-in-go)

Comment: check out go's `scanner` package. it includes tokenization for stuff like floats and ints out of the box. https://golang.org/pkg/text/scanner/

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer thanks